# CakePHP 2 - does associated table need an "id" primaryKey?

Tags: cakephp, save, sql-update

I have a table "emailsettings" which has a "belongsTo" relationship with table "users".

emailsettings has the following columns:

- user_id (INT)
- subscribed (NULL, 0 or 1)
- newsletter (NULL, 0 or 1)
- notifications (NULL, 0 or 1)

My problem is, I'm not able to update the entries, CakePHP always tries to INSERT a new row, even if I do `$this->Emailsetting->user_id = 1`.

Is it possible that an associated table needs an "id" primaryKey or can I force CakePHP to update an entry if I have the "user_id" (adding an id primaryKey doesn't make sense to me, so I figure there has to be an issue with my setup).

---

**Emailsetting.php**

```
<?php
class Emailsetting extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Emailsetting';
    public $belongsTo = array('User' => array('className' => 'User', 'foreignKey' => 'user_id'));
    public $useTable = 'email_settings';
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $hasOne = array('Profile', 'Emailsetting');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though `var $primaryKey = 'user_id';` does the trick and solve the problem, but according to `CakePHP` convention, every table should have an `id` field and I think its mostly acceptable.

Because, if you need to make a relation with one/more table(s) with `emailsettings` table, in that scenario, `id` will play a key role both for relation and query operations. Otherwise, you need to manually map all those relations ans queries to the primary key `user_id`.

Your approach is right, if working with tables, have **NO** access to change them by you.

***Moreover, a unique `id` field, often usable for different actions like `delete`, `edit` etc. May be sometimes also need for different JS/AJAX operations and so on.***

So, lastly I would recommend you to use `id` field. Becasuse, `CakePHP` is big fans of ***convention over configuration.***

Comment: good point, I will add the ID, even though in for now it doesn't do anything, this might change in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting `var $primaryKey = 'user_id';` inside my "Emailsetting.php"-Model, seems to do the trick, though is this the right approach?

Comment: Personally I include a `primary key` in my join tables, but I also know many others who do not. If you do not want to include a separate `primary key` for the join table record specifically then you are right in using `var $primaryKey = 'user_id';`. As long as this remains a `hasOne` relationship then you shouldn't run into problems.